# how to embed a file explorer or .exe program into the unity3d scene?

Tags: blender

Please tell me how can I embed a .exe program or a file explorer into my Unity3D scene? That means, I want to see my another program running inside Unity3D in the 3d space. I think it could be done really because it could be done using Blender3D and Python. So why not with Unity3D no?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that this isn't possible with Unity -- not because of technical reasons, but because this would be very uncontrollable.. 
 And if it was possible, it would probably be a Pro-only feature

Answer (score 0):

Unity actually is made for Gamedevelopement, and in games, you don't want the user to upload files themselves.

But you can indeed let the user add files or modify your game by checking the resources-folder at runtime.

If you want the user to load in files, you should probably go with Java3D or something similar, because you seem to rather develop a tool than a game. With that, a file explorer is very easy.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, I don't want the user to add a .exe into the game. For example. There's a wall in my game scene. I want to add something like a webpage or a .exe file or file explorer to my scene, to be show on the wall. Better if I could embed the explorer.exe to be shown on the wall, please tell me anyhow to do this(using coding) or something. What I want to do is, add some interactive lessons into my unity3d game(into the 3d space) Please answer!

Comment: Further, I have Unity3D Pro

Comment: Okay <br> Actually, I looked for a HTML-Plugin for Unity:<br>
Heres one for Windows: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity3d-plugin-for-embedding-webpages-on-windows-is-ready.83071/  :)

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that you cannot include an .exe file or similar into Unity...
You will probably have to 'translate' the .exe to one of Unitys programming languages.

But you can display HTML Websited with this Plugin (Pro Only):
http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/htmltexture-plugin.4990/  
there's another one:
http://uwebkit.com/

(I didn't check any of those, and I don't know wether you can click things in the website)